# SFDX - Identify tests for a specific class

Tags: unit-test, salesforcedx, deployment, sfdx-plugin, continuous-integration

I am working on a github action that is supposed to validate a "delta" package of changes in a merge request in a target sandbox.
For this validation process i am not supposed to run all tests in Org. But only tests related to the delta changes.
How can i identify tests that covers a specific class/trigger/flow using sfdx ?
Sfdx plugins suggestions are also welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to unilaterally guarantee that you'll get all dependencies correct, but here's a few ideas.

## Diff Names and Modify

Use a git diff output to see delta changes, then for each class, add "Test" to the name. This depends on a strict naming convention, and may not work for some use cases, like flows or triggers.

## Query Dependencies

Extract the diff metadata, as above, but query [MetadataComponentDependency](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_metadatacomponentdependency.htm). This gives you files that explicitly refer to another component. You might end up getting "too many" tests (e.g. a controller that calls a DML operation would also depend on triggers), but this might be acceptable. Some tweaking might be necessary.

## SOQL Searches

Explicitly state in your unit tests which classes/flow/triggers are covered, use SOSL to find and run those tests. Again, manual discipline, but if I had this as an option, that's what I'd go for.

## Use Unlocked Packages

Unlocked Packages, by definition, only run tests contained in them. If you organize your metadata into manageable chunks, you'll only have to run tests for a package you update. I'd definitely consider this as a valid option.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox for your answer, i think i'll go with the 2 first solutions combined, the 2nd one because it's easy to implement, and the first one to also cover new classes (tests will run during the validation of the package, so no data for new classes).
The 2 last solutions are harder to implement because it have a huge impact on dev process

Answer (score 2):

You can't. There's no way to determine which tests could be potentially impacted by some specific change. For example, a change to a Validation Rule can potentially cause *any* test that performs DML on any object to fail, because automation running on the object changed could itself cause changes to the object with the Validation Rule.

More or less the same principle applies to declarative and code-based automation. Even extremely sophisticated logic that walks references in the metadata to attempt to determine which objects or other classes will be implicated is necessarily imperfect.

Just run all the tests.

Comment: Thank you David for your answer. Running all tests is not really an option, running all tests takes about 50mns, the github workflow will be triggered with every PR/change in PR/new commit in PR. So, this means that a PR may take up to 6 hours to be validated (when queued with other changes)

Comment: Then you'll have to accept the risk that you are going to merge changes that break an existing test, and use a "best-guess" approach. That's not an approach that I would agree to myself. Alternately, you could consider changing your devops processes to reduce the number of test runs required.